# Comparar Array PHP con intervalo de tiempo en Horas

Tags: php, mysql, array

Teniendo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table class="table table-hover manage-u-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="10">HORA</th>
        <th width="300">ADMINISTRAR</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
//$var1, $var2, $intervalo son datos que cada cliente como administrador de su cuenta, crea en forma particular, ya que cada cliente, atiende en diferentes horarios..
  $var1 = '08:00'; //valor de BD que guarda horario inicial de atencion
  $var2 = '16:00'; //valor de BD que guarda el horario final de atencion
  $intervarlo = '15'; //cant de minutos que dura cada atencion

  $fechaInicio = new DateTime($var1);
  $fechaFin = new DateTime($var2);
  $fechaFin = $fechaFin->modify('+15 minutes');

  $rangoFechas = new DatePeriod($fechaInicio, new DateInterval('PT15M'), $fechaFin);

  foreach($rangoFechas as $fecha){ ?>
    <tr>
 <!-- TD que genera el listado de horas separadas por intervalo de 15 min, desde las 08:00 AM hasta las 16:00 para este cliente en especifico-->
      <td width="10"><?php echo $fecha->format("H:i") . PHP_EOL; ?></td>
      <td><?php
      $hora_ini = '10:15'; //hora inicial de la cita agendada proveniente de BD
      $hora_fin = '13:45'; //hora final de la cita agendada proveniente de BD
      $fecha_array[] = $fecha->format("H:i");

      if (in_array($hora_ini, $fecha_array) || in_array($hora_fin, $fecha_array)) {
        echo "OCUPADO";
      }else{
        echo "disp";
      }


      ?>

      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Como se ve en el ejemplo, trate de usar in_array para comparar los tiempos que estan en el array $fecha_array[] con $hora_ini y $hora_fin y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esta en cuadro verde, deberia ser el termino del rango de horas y por ende mostrarlo como disponible.
Lo que esta en cuadro rojo, deberian ser las horas que estan en el rango $hora_ini y $hora_fin y deberian mostrarse como no disponible.

Alguna ayuda u orientacion..
Saludos a todos.
PD: Si falta algo de informacion o aclarar dudas, con gusto lo agregare.

Comment: "Como podría mostrar en una tabla" te refieres a tabla html o de db?

Comment: mostrar en tabla html. Los datos vienen todos de base de datos, pero puse en la pregunta, datos de prueba. Saludos.

Comment: Operador between de sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo seguiría la siguiente lógica:

1. Construir un objeto `DateTime` sobre cada rango para ir sobre seguro en las comparaciones.
2. Leer el array de tiempos comparando con `if ( $time >= $timeIn->format("H:i") && $time <= $timeOut->format("H:i") )` si cada tiempo está o no en el rango.
3. Si está en el rango o no lo agrego a un array correspondiente.
4. Verifico luego los dos arrays, y si no están vacíos construyo la tabla con los tiempos que hay en ellos. Es una lógica controlada, las tablas sólo se crearán si los respectivos arrays tienen datos.

El código sería:

```
$hora_inicio = '10:30';
$hora_fin = '13:45';
$timeIn=new DateTime($hora_inicio);
$timeOut=new DateTime($hora_fin);

foreach($arrTimes as $time){
    if ( $time >= $timeIn->format("H:i") && $time <= $timeOut->format("H:i") ){
        $timeBusy[]=$time;
    }else{
        $timeFree[]=$time;
    }
}

if($timeFree){
    $tableFree="<table>";
    $tableFree.="<th>DISPONIBLES</th>";
    foreach ($timeFree as $time){
        $tableFree.="<tr><td>$time</td></tr>";
    }
    $tableFree.="<table>";
    echo $tableFree."<hr />";
}

if($timeBusy){
    $tableBusy="<table>";
    $tableBusy.="<th>NO-DISPONIBLES</th>";
    foreach ($timeBusy as $time){
        $tableBusy.="<tr><td>$time</td></tr>";
    }
    $tableBusy.="<table>";
    echo $tableBusy;
}
```

Esta sería la salida:

```html
<table>
  <th>DISPONIBLES</th>
  <tr>
    <td>08:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16:00</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
    <hr />
    <table>
      <th>NO-DISPONIBLES</th>
      <tr>
        <td>10:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10:45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13:15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13:45</td>
      </tr>
      <table>
```

---

#### EDICIÓN

Viendo tu pregunta editada, puedes hacer la comparación dentro del primer bucle también, por ejemplo:

```
foreach($rangoFechas as $fecha){
    $time=$fecha->format("H:i");
    $arrTimes[]=$time;

    if ($time >= $timeIn->format("H:i") && $time <= $timeOut->format("H:i")){
        $timeBusy[]=$time;
    }else{
        $timeFree[]=$time;
    }
}
```

Y luego verificar cada array para crear la tabla, como ya se indicó arriba.

Comment: Estimado, agradecido como siempre por su ayuda. Pero tengo una gran duda. Como genero el listado completo de los horarios que este cliente tiene, que es desde las 08:00 hasta las 16:00 y como añado la ultima informacion que me ha entregado. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Muchisimas gracias estimado. Agradecido como siempre por su buena disposicion y ayuda, Ha funcionado como necesitaba. Un abrazo y gracias nuevamente. Saludos.

Comment: estimado. consulta. existe la posibilidad de mostrar los resultados en una sola tabla, que el correlativo de las horas sea ascendente y las horas ocupadas se muestre obviamente "OCUPADO"?

Answer (score 0):

no es la manera más óptima pero debería funcionar.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Horas Disponible</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $query = mysqli_query("mi conexion", "SELECT horas FROM tabla");
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $validador = true;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                if ($row['horas'] == $value) {
                    $validador = false;
                }
            }
            if ($validador) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: estimado, acabo de editar mi pregunta, ya que estaba demasiado ambigua y no representaba realmente el problema en cuestion. Disculpe la molestia que pudo haber causado. Saludos y gracias por su informacion